# Datastructure is best for rules like Item can not be Shipped to a particular postalCode

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm, recursive-datastructures

I have a Shipping Restriction table with Rules like:
ProductClass:'Suites' Can not be Shipped to 'Georgia',
ProductClass:'Body Spray' and Hazmat:True can not be shipped to Postal Code:322001
ProductClass:'Baby Toys' can not be shipped to 'US',
and we have a rule like, I Can not ship any item to 'Arizona' state.

ProductClass, Hazmat, and ShippingMethod are one group (zero or more properties can have values).
Same way PostalCode, state, country are another group(only one will be filled with value per rule).
This is configuration/static data and it will be huge(more than 10k rules)

| RuleId | Product Class | Hazmat | ShippingMethod | Postal Code | State | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Suits |  |  |  | Georgia |  |
| 2 | Body Spray | TRUE |  | 322001 |  |  |
| 3 | Body Spray |  |  | 322009 |  |  |
| 4 | Baby Toys |  |  |  |  | US |
| 5 | Guns |  |  |  | Florida |  |
| 6 |  |  | Air |  | Hawaii |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  | Arizona |  |

Now I got Order with 3 items like:
Item1: ProductClass 'Suits', Hazmat:false, ShippingMethod:'ByAir', postalCode:322002, state:'Texas'
Item2: ProductClass 'Guns', Hazmat:false, ShippingMethod:'ByAir', postalCode:322009, state:'Texas'
Item3: ProductClass 'Baby Toys', Hazmat:false, ShippingMethod:'ByAir', postalCode:322011, state:'Florida'

Expectation is an Order can contain 5 to 15 items.
When I receive order(in my example I received order with 3 items), I need to run thru all these restriction rules configured above, if there is one/many restriction rule matches for an item, then need to record them.

What will be the best algorithm to achieve this in Java.

Comment: Dont close this thread, let me know if you guys didnt understand question, please let me know which part is not understand, will try to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the restriction table has 10k items, the first question is how many orders to you expect to need to handle.

If this number is relatively small, then just run each item and find if there are any lines that match what you need.

However, if this number very large, it will make sense to do some preprocessing beforehand and convert the restriction table into some data structure that makes checking the items easier.

The first data structure that comes to (my) mind is a nested object that hold one of the columns as a property.
Then those hold more nested object with another column as property.

Essentially this would allow each line to check a number of properties in an object rather than finding a line in an array of 10k items.

Comment: Any algo like Tree/graph I can use to avoid no.of iterations.

Comment: This data structure is essentially a tree. That would give you 'h' cost to check every record where 'h' is the height of the tree which is the number of the columns

Comment: Could you please throw some light on how to represent the data, not able to view it.

Comment: What does an empty cell in the table mean?

Comment: No data for that particular cell.